# Flutter: How to resize an image with Image plugin

Tags: dart, flutter

I am attempting to resize an image with the flutter plugin "Image" https://pub.dartlang.org/packages/image

The method I am using per the instructions

```
  File resizeMyImage(File resizeThisFile) {
    // decodeImage will identify the format of the image and use the appropriate
    // decoder.
    File myCompressedFile;
    Image image = decodeImage(resizeThisFile.readAsBytesSync());

    // Resize the image to a 120x? thumbnail (maintaining the aspect ratio).
    Image thumbnail = copyResize(image, 120);

    // Save the thumbnail as a PNG.
    myCompressedFile = new Io.File('thumbnail.png')..writeAsBytesSync(encodePng(thumbnail));

   return myCompressedFile;
  }
```

The error I get

```
E/flutter (22897): FileSystemException: Cannot open file, path = 'thumbnail.png' (OS Error: Read-only file system, errno = 30)
```

Any help is greatly appreciated - thanks.

The working resize class looks like this. Hope it helps someone.

```
import 'dart:async';
import 'dart:io' as Io;
import 'dart:io';
import 'package:image/image.dart';
import 'package:path_provider/path_provider.dart';

class ResizeImage {

  String tempPath;

  Future main() async {
  }


  Future<Io.File> resizeMyImage(File resizeThisFile) async {
    Directory tempDir = await getTemporaryDirectory();
    tempPath = tempDir.path;

    // decodeImage will identify the format of the image and use the appropriate
    // decoder.
    File myCompressedFile;
    Image image = decodeImage(resizeThisFile.readAsBytesSync());

    // Resize the image to a 120x? thumbnail (maintaining the aspect ratio).
    Image thumbnail = copyResize(image, 120);

    // Save the thumbnail as a PNG.
    print('resizeMyImage............tempPath: '+tempPath);
    myCompressedFile = new Io.File(tempPath+'thumbnail.png')..writeAsBytesSync(encodePng(thumbnail));

   return myCompressedFile;
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't create a file in the current directory, because it is read-only as the error message states.

https://pub.dartlang.org/packages/path_provider allows you to get the path to a valid directory

> ```
> Directory tempDir = await getTemporaryDirectory();
> String tempPath = tempDir.path;
>
> Directory appDocDir = await getApplicationDocumentsDirectory();
> String appDocPath = appDocDir.path;
> ```

Comment: Thanks for the assist.  I thought the same thing and looked at the documentation to see if they were using the plugin to find path and they are not so I thought I was missing something.

Comment: Whom do you mean with "they"? What are you referring to ?

Comment: The creators of the plugin from the pub.dartlang link. They have an example within the plugin package.  Thanks again for the help. I think I have it working now. Is it safe to assume that the pub.dartlang.org packages are not specifically for flutter ?

Comment: No, only when `Flutter` is the only tag. Others can be used in Dart command line or browser apps.